# How to Make an excel autofit generated by jxl.jar and jasperReports.jar

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using this code to make the excel.

```
exporterXLS = new JExcelApiExporter();
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, file2);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
```

I searched the whole api but didn't find any thing useable.
 Please help me out from this problem.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please help me - what exactly do you mean by 'autofit'?

Comment: As you can see, there is an open issue to make this feature at http://jasperforge.org: http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport/tracker/view.php?id=5276

Comment: @home 'autofit' all the rows and columns should be display with same hight and width.Thanks for your precious time!!!

Comment: @AlexK Any work around for this problem.Any help will appreciated Thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are these properties already:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column
```

And:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row
```

Their value must be set to `true`.